# Is there an IDE that works with CUDA on mac osx lion?

Tags: c, eclipse, cuda

I'm trying to learn Cuda and its very interesting but I'm having problems creating code without a bit of help from an IDE.  I know Java/Python but I'm unfamiliar with C/C++ so I have been using eclipse and Xcode to help me with commands and finding things(via code code completion).  I can't seem to get these options for CUDA?

I have seen examples and can build them find(nvcc is working) but without the IDE to help catch some of my mistakes I'm a bit lost editing the code in just a text editor.  I found a toolkit plugin for eclipse but although it seems to install I think its for a older build of eclipse because most of the options in the instructions do not match my version(Indigo). Nvidia has a plugin for Visual studio only on their site(I'd rather not install windows on my mac to use Cuda).

I'm sorry if this sounds bad but I'm curious to how people are developing cuda on Mac's.  I don't care what IDE I use as long as it helps me see the options and warn me if I have syntax issues,etc..(I'm not the best programmer but switching IDE's for me has just been a matter of finding out where things are so I'm really fine with any solution as long as it helps me as I'm learning).

Comment: There is a GTC 2012 session on 05/16/2012 titled Nsight IDE for Linux and Mac with the desription: Nsight IDE for Linux and Mac is an all-in-one development environment that lets you develop, debug and optimize CUDA code in an integrated UI environment. If you were waiting for an IDE on Linux and Mac then this session is for you. This session provides a detail usage walk-through of a fully CUDA aware source editor, build integration of the CUDA toolchain, graphical debugger for both CPU and GPU, and graphical profiler to enable performance optimization.

Comment: @GregSmith sounds interesting and I did read that nvidia would have big news for mac/linux developers at that conference.  Do you know if this product is already released? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/)!

You can read [Qt Creator + CUDA + Linux](http://cudaspace.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/qt-creator-cuda-linux/) for inspiration on how to setup the build environment on Mac OS X.

Comment: I'm a n00b, sorry.  I always thought QT creator was for graphics related work, will it still be okay for using CUDA for general purpose programming?

Comment: I use it all the time for non-graphics development. :)

Comment: I also recommend it. I've been using QT Creator for a year for R&D with CUDA apps that run in console.

Comment: @pQB Nice posts, by the way, too bad you stopped blogging. If you also recommend it, consider upvoting the answer :)

Comment: @karlphillip Thanks you. It seems in need a new reset ;).

Answer (score 3):

Nsight Eclipse Edition is available as a part of the CUDA Toolkit 5.0 (no additional download required).

Answer (score 1):

You could think about using JCuda:

http://www.jcuda.de/

Comment: I'll check it out.  I saw that before but I thought it was just libraries to let Java talk to Cuda. I figured since Cuda is like C, its a good opportunity to learn C/C++.

Comment: Wait..sorry, I'm slow(its late), I think your suggesting I use Java to code Cuda?  Thats a option for sure, but I'd rather do it all in C right now since I can learn and plus all the examples in the books/tutorials seem to be in C.

Comment: JCuda is CUDA bindings in Java.  Looks like a 1:1 port to me.

Comment: Thanks Duffmo.  I'll study it a bit and keep this option open, but ideally I would like something that is in c/c++ as it'll allow me to follow the tutorials and example code alot more easily.  Good to know this option exists though.

Answer (score 1):

There is XCode plug-in for CUDA development. I found it [there](https://code.google.com/p/beagle-lib/downloads/detail?name=NVCuda.pbplugin.zip&can=4&q=). There is the [main discussion on nvidia.com](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=60336&st=0)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code + this extension:
https://github.com/gangliao/VS-Code-Cuda.
For me, Visual Studio Code is my favorite IDE for every language I found out there